# Rails Friendly_id Duplicate Key Value Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I am working on a Rails site and I am having problems with a script that is supposed to take a bunch of local times and convert them into GMT (don't ask...) and save those values to a new column. The problem is that I keep getting the error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_slugs_on_n_s_s_and_s" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
: UPDATE "slugs" SET "sequence" = 3, "scope" = 'utah-museum-of-contemporary-art' WHERE "id" = 9
```

This error is caused by an occurrence of `scope` and `sequence` being the same (which should not be happening). I think that the problem is a result of having a sequence of `2` and `3`, but no `1` (the slug (`id=9`) is NOT the same as what exists in the DB). Is there a way to correct this issue and get `friendly_id` to do this correctly?

Comment: Same problem here, did you finally find a solution?

Comment: I did find the solution, but I am afraid I don't remember it. However, I remember that it had something to do with a missing sequence value. e.g. 1,3,4 existed, but 2 does not. So the next index will be count+1 (which in this case will be 4), but that already exists.